# Avoiding file replication in MS 365 products

Tags: office365, onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have an existing file/folder on my Onedrive. I would like to achieve the following:

Make this file/folder available in the "files tab" of a Teams channel or a shared Sharepoint folder without having to re-upload the resource such that any change in the original file/folder will auto-sync with the file/folder in Teams/Sharepoint. Sort of sharing the file and adding the shared link to other locations/apps on MS 365 to avoid duplication.

Is there a way to achieve this?

TIA.

Comment: Are you attempting to cross Business to a personal account domain?  Teams implies business but OneDrive (non-business) implies a personal account

Comment: Its Onedrive for business - part of Microsoft 365 for business suite

Comment: Shouldn’t OneDrive/Teams be pointed to the same SharePoint files already?

Comment: Each Team/channel has its own SharePoint site/space. The problem is I cannot "Add" my existing Onedrive files to the Team's SharePoint folder. At least not without re-uploading it to the SharePoint folder, which in essence defeats the purpose of a connected ecosystem by creating a duplicate.